# oracle query timeout

Tags: oracle, timeout

simple query causes ora - 01013 error

```
select count (*) as counter, 'month_stat' as name
from s_contact_x
where created < last_upd
and (sysdate - last_upd) < 1
```

> Message: Query failed  ORA-01013: user
>   requested cancel of current operation

This select query is succesfully running in TOAD editor, but it takes 3-5 min get resultset.

As I understood, this problem corresponding with oracle query timeout, how we can set it in query?

Comment: From where you call this query when it return ORA-01013?

Comment: Only time I've seen that I was getting ORA-600s in the alert log. In terms of performance, if last_upd is indexed (and maybe even if it isn't) you might be better off doing `and last_upd > sysdate - 1`.

Comment: @Michael, query is running in adapter for management system, I cannot change any additional connection settings, only query

Comment: @Alex, changing where clause gives no difference

Comment: The timeout setting would be in that management system and not something the database does.  Adding some indexes should get that running a lot faster.  It shouldn't taking minutes to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested, you should first look at changing settings and adding indexes.  If that doesn't work then you may want to look into using parallelism to speed up the query:

```
select /*+ parallel(s_contact_x) */ count (*) as counter, 'month_stat' as name
from s_contact_x
where created < last_upd
and (sysdate - last_upd) < 1
```